# Robocopy not excluding changed files

Tags: robocopy

I am copying a full directory over and am trying to exclude changed files. Note that I am doing this in `Powershell`.

```
robocopy "D:\Projects\Publishes\css" "D:\Projects\robocopy test\css" /xc
```

However my changed files at destination are being over-written. I can't use exclude older or newer files by the nature of my situation so these are out.

**NOTE:**

On the `MSDN` page it says `/xct` to exclude changed files but if I do this I get the following error:

```
ERROR : Invalid Parameter #3 : "/xct"
```

From other examples I've seen `/xc` so that is what I'm using here.

Answer (score 0):

I translate your requirement as:

> Some files on the destination directory have been changed. Don't replace those.

I think what you are looking for is the `/XO` flag

```
robocopy "D:\Projects\Publishes\css" "D:\Projects\robocopy test\css" /xo /e
```

This translates to

> Do not overwrite **newer** files on the **destination** directory

Your `/xn` flag actually means

> Do not copy **newer** files from the **source** directory

Sightly different.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid using the time stamp at all. By the nature of the work, some of the files get updated/generated automatically by a script and there is potential for the files to have the exact same time stamp. Really what I'm trying to get at is am I using `xc` incorrectly? I mean, shouldn't my code work as is?